# What is the Oracle equivalent of SQL Server's IsNull() function?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

In SQL Server we can type `IsNull()` to determine if a field is null.  Is there an equivalent function in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

`coalesce` is supported in both Oracle and SQL Server and serves essentially the same function as `nvl` and `isnull`. (There are some important differences, `coalesce` can take an arbitrary number of arguments, and returns the first non-null one. The return type for `isnull` matches the type of the first argument, that is not true for `coalesce`, at least on SQL Server.)

Comment: +1: `COALESCE` is ANSI, supported by Postgres, MySQL...  The only caveat is that it doesn't necessarily perform as fast as native syntax.

Comment: +1 for `COALESCE`, which has one important benefit over `NVL`: it does shortcut evaluation, whereas `NVL` always evaluates both parameters. Compare `COALESCE(1,my_expensive_function)` with `NVL(1,my_expensive_function)`.

Comment: This `COALESE()` function is great and you can read about it on [MSDOC> COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)-- this same syntax works on Oracle.  If your data has empty strings instead of NULLS you might need something like this: `COALESCE(TRIM(Tbl.myField1), TRIM(Tbl.myField2)) AS "myNewField"`.

Answer (score 142):

Instead of `ISNULL()`, use `NVL()`.

T-SQL:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SomeNullableField, 'If null, this value') FROM SomeTable
```

PL/SQL:

```
SELECT NVL(SomeNullableField, 'If null, this value') FROM SomeTable
```

Answer (score 45):

Also use `NVL2` as below if you want to return other value from the `field_to_check`:

```
NVL2( field_to_check, value_if_NOT_null, value_if_null )
```

Usage: [ORACLE/PLSQL: NVL2 FUNCTION](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl2.php)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the condition `if x is not null then...`. It's not a function. There's also the `NVL()` function, a good example of usage here: [NVL function ref](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php).