# sql server difference between a blank column and column with value = 'NULL'

Tags: sql-server-2008

In sql server, I see a strange behaviour:
When I do

`select col1+ ' ' + cast(col2 as varchar(10)) as concat_col`

it returns me a column with a value = NULL (not a blank column).

My suspicion is that it is because col2 has a value = NULL (not blank column).
So what is the reason for this behavior? But more importantly, what is the meaning of a column with value = NULL as opposed to a blank column? I do not imagine somebody went in the table and updated all the columns with value = NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULL means that the field does not have any value. You can use ISNULL function to convert a null value into something that you want.The following will hopefully give you the correct result  (will not give null)

```
select ISNULL(col1,'')+ ' ' + cast(ISNULL(col2,'') as varchar(10)) as concat_col
```

Comment: SO this is different from oracle i guess. when i open an oracle table in toad, both null and '' show as blank column

Comment: In Oracle you have to  use `NVL` and you can use `coalesce` which is supported in both. More in [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3524035/777982)

Answer (score 0):

Blank is a value while null is completely nothing.

Think of zero is a number while null is nothing.