# TSQL Counting Nulls - where all grouped items have NULL field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Just trying to wrap my head around the logic/commands needed:

I have a contacts table. Each contact has a client in a many-to-one fashion.
I am trying to get any clientIDs where all contacts have a NULL value for email.

Example data:

```
ContactID   EmailAddress    ClientID
1           NULL                3
907         NULL                3
2468        NULL                3
2469        email@email.com     4
1077        NULL                4
908         email@email.com     4
2           email@email.com     4
3           email@email.com     5
909         email@email.com     5
```

Thanks!

Comment: So for the above example 3 will be the answer right?

Comment: related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523036/what-is-the-oracle-equivalent-of-sql-servers-isnull-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a grouped aggregate and a [`HAVING`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) clause (and assuming blank email addresses can be treated the same as nulls):

```
SELECT 
    ClientID
    FROM ClientEmails
    GROUP BY ClientID
    HAVING MAX(LEN(ISNULL(EmailAddress, ''))) = 0;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0c29f/7)

Comment: Nice. Is this database agnostic ? Also, can you tell me if my query is okay too. thank you. chenqui.

Comment: HAVING is ANSI. `ISNULL` and `LEN` aren't - `COALESCE` would be more portable than `ISNULL` (and other alternatives exist, e.g. Oracle has NVL). Most DB's have equivalents to `LEN`, e.g. `LENGTH `. Your query is fine - `COUNT(x)` excluding NULLs seems to be [standard behaviour](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/sql/0596004818/4dot2dot-ansi-sql-aggregate-functions/id3752538)

Answer (score 7):

Would this help ?

```
select *
from
(
select clientId, 
COUNT(emailAddress) as Mailz, 
COUNT(contactId) as Contacts
from contacts
group by clientId
) as src
where (Mailz = 0 and contacts > 0)
```

Comment: Can you also elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    ClientID
FROM(
    SELECT 
        ClientID, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN EmailAddress IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) a,
        COUNT(*) b
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY ClientID
)x WHERE a=b
```

Comment: can be done without having a subquery, just filter it in `HAVING` clause eg. `HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN EmailAddress IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`