# Clubbing update statements using case in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to update the same column with different error codes based on the error condition.

The update conditions (Separately) :

```
UPDATE MEM_SRC_EXTN
SET INT_VALUE_1 =100
WHERE ISNULL(TYPE_VALUE,'') =''
OR ISNULL(TYPE,'') =''
OR ISNULL(VALUE_1,'') =''
OR ISNULL(VALUE_2,'') ='';

UPDATE MEM_SRC_EXTN EXTN
SET INT_VALUE_1=222
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1
FROM CMC_MEM_SRC SRC 
WHERE EXTN.TYPE_VALUE = SRC.TN_ID);

UPDATE MEM_SRC_EXTN
SET INT_VALUE_1=333 
GROUP BY TYPE_VALUE 
HAVING COUNT(VALUE_1)>1;
```

As I have to club these 3 update conditions into one based on condition, so that It first checks the condition and then update column values instead of triggering all 3 update statement each time.

I come up with this solution but not sure will whether this will work or not?

```
UPDATE MEM_SRC_EXTN EXTN
SET INT_VALUE_1 = CASE 
                          WHEN (ISNULL(TYPE_VALUE,'') ='' OR ISNULL(TYPE,'') ='' OR ISNULL(VALUE_1,'') =''OR ISNULL(VALUE_2,'') ='')
                          THEN 100
                          WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CMC_MEM_SRC SRC WHERE EXTN.TYPE_VALUE = SRC.TN_ID)
                          THEN 222
                          WHEN GROUP BY TYPE_VALUE HAVING COUNT(VALUE_1)>1
                          THEN 333
                          ELSE 000
                        END
```

Comment: That is indeed the correct approach. Test it and write back if it's not working for some reason.

Comment: There is no `isnull` function in Oracle, use `coalesce` or `nvl` instead - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523036/what-is-the-oracle-equivalent-of-sql-servers-isnull-function

Comment: Also, an empty string is considered `NULL` in Oracle.  So, `NVL(TYPE_VALUE,'') = ''` will be `FALSE` if `TYPE_VALUE` is `NULL`.  I expect you want `NVL(TYPE_VALUE,'#NULL#') = '#NULL#'`, or something like that, where '#NULL#' is some generic string that could not be an actual value of `TYPE_VALUE`.

Comment: Also `WHEN GROUP BY`... that's not right at all.  Someone needs to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider a `MERGE` statement for this.  Like so:

```
MERGE INTO mem_src_extn t USING 
( 
SELECT mse.rowid row_id,
       CASE WHEN mse.type_value IS NULL OR mse."TYPE" IS NULL OR mse.VALUE_1 IS NULL or mse.VALUE_2 IS NULL THEN 100
            WHEN ( SELECT count(*) FROM cmc_mem_src cms WHERE cms.tn_id = mse.type_value ) = 0 THEN 222
            WHEN count(mse.value_1) over ( partition by type_value ) > 1 THEN 333
       ELSE '000' int_value_1  
FROM   mem_src_extn mse
) u
ON ( t.rowid = u.row_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.int_value_1 = u.int_value_1 WHERE u.inv_value_1 != '000';
```

`MERGE` statements have an added bonus for developers -- you can simply run the `SELECT` part of them to see what your results are going to be.  That makes it easier to debug.

Also note, your original `UPDATE` statements would not update anything to `000`, but your proposed solution would.  So, it's not clear what your requirement there is.  My solution does not update anything to `000`, thanks to the `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` clause of the `MERGE`.  You can remove that if you want to set rows not meeting any of the three conditions to `000`.

Answer (score 0):

The first of all you should use correct order of statement. If `WHEN GROUP BY TYPE_VALUE HAVING COUNT(VALUE_1)>1` was last then in case it should be first. 
Besides you cant write `WHEN GROUP BY TYPE_VALUE HAVING COUNT(VALUE_1)>1`.
`= ''` in orcle is the same as `= null` it's not true and not false use is null 
You may rewrite it to subquery

```
UPDATE MEM_SRC_EXTN EXTN
SET INT_VALUE_1 = CASE 
     WHEN exists (SELECT NULL 
                    FROM MEM_SRC_EXTN sub_extn
                   WHERE sub_extn.TYPE_VALUE = EXTN.TYPE_VALUE 
                      OR (sub_extn.TYPE_VALUE is NULL AND EXTN.TYPE_VALUE IS NULL)
                   GROUP BY TYPE_VALUE 
                  HAVING COUNT(VALUE_1)>1)
       THEN 333
     WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                        FROM CMC_MEM_SRC SRC 
                       WHERE EXTN.TYPE_VALUE = SRC.TN_ID)
       THEN 222
     WHEN TYPE_VALUE is null OR TYPE is null OR VALUE_1 is null OR VALUE_2 is null
       THEN 100
     ELSE 000
     END
```

but this query are agly and may be you may use something else. Please think about `merge`