# Columns with Null Values in SQL Server vs Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, null

In Oracle: ='' and 'is null' return NULL Values

```
 SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE WHERE COL1='' --> RETURN COL1 WITH NULL VALUES
 SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 IS NULL --> RETURN COL1 WITH NULL VALUES
```

Both queries return the same set of rows.

In Microsoft SQL:

```
SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE WHERE COL1='' --> RETURN COL1 WITH <BLANK> VALUES
SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 IS NULL --> RETURN COL1 WITH <NULL> VALUES
```

Here the first and second queries return different sets of rows.

Why is there a difference between the Microsoft SQL result set and the Oracle result set?

How could I retrieve both set of rows in Microsoft SQL? (Values which are '' and values which are NULL).

Comment: Because `''(empty string)` is **NOT** equal to `NULL`. Not sure about `Oracle`

Comment: In `Oracle`, an empty string is automatically converted to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server `''` is not null. In Oracle its a bit complicated `x char := ''` is not null in `PL/SQL` but as `varchar2` empty string `''` is exactly same as `null` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null) And in case of queries this is `varchar2` so condition `COL = ''` is never true.

If you need condition that will work in both DBs please use `coalesce` function.

```
select * from TAB 
  where coalesce(COL,'SOME_UNIQUE_STRING') = coalesce(FILTER_PARAM, 'SOME_UNIQUE_STRING')
```

Such condition should return rows when `COLUMN` is equal to `FILTER` as well as both are null or empty strings.

Comment: Thanks Kacper for the info.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve both sets of data, you could use `isnull`.

```
SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE WHERE ISNULL(COL1, '') = ''
```

Oracle automatically converts empty strings to null values, and sql server does not, which is why the result sets are different.

You can find more information on this here:
[Why does Oracle 9i treat an empty string as NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null)

Comment: There is no `isnull` in Oracle. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523036/what-is-the-oracle-equivalent-of-sql-servers-isnull-function

Comment: Thanks much for the link.  I could now understand the  differences.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid defining a unique string, you could use a case statement.

This way we evaluate col when null or empty set to the same value for comparison.  Since case to my knowledge is DBMS independent this should work in both.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE case when col is NULL or col = '' then 1 else 0 end = 1
```