# insert Default value For a column while inserting data from other table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am facing an issue when I am inserting data into table1 by selecting data from table2
like

`INSERT INTO table1
   SELECT * FROM table2`

So there is a column in both table like field1 for which value is null in table2.
But in table I have set the default value for field1 
after executing ,

```
  INSERT INTO table1
     SELECT * FROM table2
```

I am having null value  for field1 insted of getting default value of it what i set.

Answer (score 2):

You Can Specify the column names and then set the value in your **Select** Statement

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, field3, ...)
SELECT field1, 
       CASE WHEN field2 IS NOT NULL THEN field2
            ELSE 'Your_default_value' END , 
       field3, ...
FROM table2
```

Comment: For some rows it is null and for other rows there is value for field1 so i want for null value it should set default value .

Comment: I think your query will set all the records with default value for field1

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field2, field3, ...)
SELECT field2, field3, ...
FROM table2
```

You just skip the column for which default value oyu want to use and it will be automatically populated with default.

Comment: As a side note you should avoid building inserts without explicitly listing columns as these will easily break once the table is restructured

Comment: Thanks for your time and solution , why I need to mention all the column names simply why it is not inserting default value by executing "insert into table1 select * from table2. can you tell ?

Comment: Well, how is the database supposed to know what you're omitting? First column, last column, s.t. in the middle? The insert without column names works only if everything matches - if not you need to specify the mapping by listing the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, One way to achieve this is use of CASE EXPRESSION, Assuming that `field2` is column which you wants to put default value

```
INSERT INTO TableName1 (field1, field2, field3, ...)
SELECT field1, CASE WHEN field2 IS NULL THEN 'DefaultValue' ELSE field2 END, field3, ...
FROM TableName2
```

Comment: Thanks Its working ,Really thankful to you but why is that simple query is not working if i have already set the default value at table level.

Comment: Since you are trying insert null value in respective column, when you are not inserting any thing in respective column that time only default value get inserted.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using NVL**

INSERT INTO TableName1 (field1, field2, field3, ...)

SELECT field1, **NVL(field2,'Your Default Value')**, field3, ...
FROM TableName2

Comment: [IsNull does not seem to be available on Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523036/what-is-the-oracle-equivalent-of-sql-servers-isnull-function)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
INSERT INTO DESTINATION_TABLE(A, B, C, D, E, F)
   SELECT W, X, Y, 'Some custom value', CASE WHEN Z IS NULL THEN 'Some other value' ELSE Z
FROM SOURCE_TABLE
WHERE ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you want to replace a null value, use COALESCE. COALESCE is available in both Oracle and SQL Server, it doesn't evaluate arguments unless needed (NVL always evaluates the second argument), and it is simpler than a case statement:

```
Insert into table1(field1, field2)
  select field1, coalesce(field2, field3, field4, 'novalue') from table2;
```

One big difference between NVL and COALESCE, if the second argument has side effects, you could come up with different results.