# MS ACCESS 2007, In SQL Pass through Query Getting Error like "missing expression"

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, ms-access-2007

Getting Error in MS ACCESS 2007,

```
Error: Error at Command Line:15 Column:11 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression 00936. 00000 - "missing expression"
```

Under SQL Pass Through Query i was trying to run below query:

tbl_Loss_Curr_Day - SQL Linked table
tbl_Loss_Prior_Day - SQL Linked table
PCOMMON - Oracle linked table
PROGRAM_CODE - Oracle linked table
BUSINESS_UNIT- - Oracle linked table

```
SELECT LC.num_policy_x,
   LC.num_edition,
   LC.cde_company,
   LC.num_claim,
   LC.cde_accident_state_abbr,
   LC.nme_insured,
   LC.dte_loss,
   LC.nme_adjuster,
   LC.cde_bus_unit,
   LC.dte_reported,
   PC.AC_FLAG,
   PC.G78_PROGRAM_CODE,
   LPC.G78_DESCRIPTION,
   BU.R21_DESCRIPTION, 
   Sum([LC].[amt_dir_resv]-(IsNull([LP].[amt_dir_resv],0))) AS Loss_Resv, 
Sum([LC].[amt_exp_resv]-(IsNull([LP].[amt_exp_resv],0))) AS Exp_Resv, 
Sum(([LC].[amt_dir_paid]-(IsNull([LP].[amt_dir_paid],0)))-([LC].[amt_dir_rcvrd]-(IsNull([LP].[amt_dir_rcvrd],0)))) AS Loss_Paid, 
Sum(([LC].[amt_exp_paid]-(IsNull([LP].[amt_exp_paid],0)))-([LC].[amt_exp_rcvrd]-(IsNull([LP].[amt_exp_rcvrd],0)))) AS Exp_Paid, 
Sum(IsNull([LP].[amt_dir_incurred],0)) AS Loss_BegIncurred, Sum(IsNull([LC].[amt_dir_incurred],0)) AS Loss_EndIncurred, 
Sum(IsNull([LP].[amt_exp_incurred],0)) AS Exp_BegIncurred, Sum(IsNull([LC].[amt_exp_incurred],0)) AS Exp_EndIncurred, 
Sum([LC].[amt_dir_incurred]-(IsNull([LP].[amt_dir_incurred],0))) AS Loss_ChgIncurred, 
Sum([LC].[amt_exp_incurred]-(IsNull([LP].[amt_exp_incurred],0))) AS Exp_ChgIncurred FROM ((((tbl_Loss_Curr_Day AS LC
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Loss_Prior_Day AS LP ON LC.cde_coverage = LP.cde_coverage
    AND LC.num_unit = LP.num_unit
    AND LC.num_claim = LP.num_claim
    AND LC.num_claim_sfx = LP.num_claim_sfx)
   LEFT JOIN PCOMMON AS PC ON LC.cde_bus_unit=PC.R21_BUSINESS_UNIT
   AND LC.num_edition=PC.A06_EDITION
   AND trim(LC.num_policy_x)=trim(PC.A00_PNUM)))
  LEFT JOIN PROGRAM_CODE AS LPC ON lpc.G78_PROGRAM_CODE=PC.G78_PROGRAM_CODE)
  LEFT JOIN BUSINESS_UNIT AS BU ON BU.R21_BUSINESS_UNIT = PC.R21_BUSINESS_UNIT WHERE LC.cde_current = 'C'  AND PC.D14_Status NOT IN ('SC') GROUP BY LC.num_policy_x,         LC.num_edition,
     LC.cde_company,
     LC.num_claim,
     LC.cde_accident_state_abbr,
     LC.nme_insured,
     LC.dte_loss,
     LC.nme_adjuster,
     LC.cde_bus_unit,
     LC.dte_reported,
     PC.AC_FLAG,
     PC.G78_PROGRAM_CODE,
     LPC.G78_DESCRIPTION,
     BU.R21_DESCRIPTION ORDER BY LC.cde_company,
     LC.cde_bus_unit,
     LC.num_claim;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Oracle equivalent of SQL Server's IsNull() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523036/what-is-the-oracle-equivalent-of-sql-servers-isnull-function)

Comment: How are you expecting to run a Pass-Through query on a Join of SQL Server **and** Oracle tables?